Exchanged gear cable - Large shifter doesn't click
I have exchanged the inner and outer cables for both front and rear derailleur on my road bike (Shimano 105 5800). When I tried indexing the gears, I noticed that both shifters don't click when I actuate the large paddle. The small paddles click, but infinite times.
The cables are routed internally, but I think they are routed correctly (I even redid that). But even when I pull the cable a bit out of the frame, I still have the same issue, so I don't think it is too much friction in the frame.
When I unseat the cable inside the shifters, they click correctly. Therefore I feel I did something wrong when routing the cable through the shifter, but I can't see a way to do that differently. The way the cable end sits in the shifter doesn't look quite right to me though. Is there anything I could have missed when threading the cable in?
Edited:
Turns out the little ball ends of the gear cables were not seated correctly in the mechanism indeed. Now everything shifts.


is there a way for you to drop a video link of the issue, it could be much easier to help you with a video rather than explain it

not really. On the other side, cable comes out in its guide and the plastic cover is in place. I can press the small lever - it clicks, but nothing happens. The large lever seems to be blocked around halfway. Same problem left and right, so I suspect I have made the same mistake on both shifters.

Start by unclamping a shifter from the bar and separate the shifter from the internal routing.  With a bare cable hanging out of the shifter, does it pull cable as expected?

Excellent work!  Can you please post a brief answer and accept that, so the question is marked as solved ?
